# Which is the equivalent of JLayeredPane in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, jlayeredpane

In the swing we have the JlayeredPane, which is the equivalent in javafx?
Take this code for example:

```
    JLayeredPane panel = new JLayeredPane();
    
    JLabel test1 = new JLabel("Test 1");
    JLabel test2 = new JLabel("Test 2");
    
    panel.setLayer(test1, 0);
    panel.add(test1);
    
    panel.setLayer(test2, 1);
    panel.add(test2);
```

How can be translate in javafx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of the Swing `JLayeredPane` would be the [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html).

> The z-order of the children is defined by the order of the children
>   list with the 0th child being the bottom and last child on top. If a
>   border and/or padding have been set, the children will be layed out
>   within those insets.

Where "children list" means the `ObservableList` returned by `StackPane.getChildren()`.